# Gaussian Quadrature Roots and Coefficients

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am studying Burden's book, Numerical Analysis. It says:

> Gaussian quadrature **chooses the points for evaluation in an optimal**, rather than equally spaced way.

However, roots and coefficients (weights) are constant for every function. How does Gaussian Quadrature method choose the points for optimal evaluation, when roots and coefficients are constant and provided in advance?

Shouldn't they depend on the integrand and bounds? Why do we always use the same roots and coefficients?

Answer (score 2):

They write "Gaussian quadrature chooses the points for evaluation in an optimal, rather than equally spaced, manner"

Now read on: "... To measure this accuracy, we assume that the best choice of 
these values is that producing the exact result for the largest class of polynomials."

A better description is found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature): 
"An n-point Gaussian quadrature rule, named after Carl Friedrich Gauss, is a qadrature rule constructed to yield an exact result for polynomials of degree 2n − 1"

For weight function 1 this leads to Legendre polynomials and their zeros,
see [Gauss-Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature).

For other integrals with other weight functions the optimal nodes and weights are different.